# How do I set Google Docs not always with https?

Tags: google-drive

I use Google Chrome Browser. **Is it possible to set Google Docs not always with https?**

Comment: Why would you not want to use HTTPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**. Google requires SSL for their Google Docs service.